# Unable to push_back() custom type into a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to push_back a Point type object i created into a vector using the said function but i keep getting wrong values when printing the element.
In fact, the purpose is to get a series of values from a source file called "src.txt" with arranged values to compose the `vector<Point> v`.
I'm certain that this is just a simple fix, but i can't find it!
Check the commented section wright after the vector declaration please.
Any help will be much appreciated.

I have a Point class:

**point.h**

```
class Point {
public:

    Point();
    Point(int x, int y);
    int getX() {return this->x;}
    int getY() {return this->y;}
private:
    int x;
    int y;
};
```

**point.cpp**

```
#include "point.h"

Point::Point() 
    :x{0},
     y{0}
{}

Point::Point(int xx, int yy)
    :x{xx}, 
     y{yy}
{}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <vector>
#include "point.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ostream& operator << (ostream& os, Point& p);
istream& operator >> (istream& is, Point& p);
void init() {
    try {
        cout << "Source filename: ";
        string src;
        cin >> src; src += ".txt";
        ifstream file{src};
        if(!file) throw runtime_error("Could not open file...");

        vector<Point> v;
        Point p(5,6);
        cout << p;                   //displays x=5; y=6
        v.push_back(p);

        for(Point p : v) cout << p; //now it displays:
                                    //x=-2147193408; y=1


//        for(Point p; file >> p; ) v.push_back(p);
//        for(Point pp : v) cout << pp;

    }
    catch(exception& e) {
        cout << "Error: " << e.what() << endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    init();
}
//output point operator
ostream& operator << (ostream& os, Point& p) {
    os << "x = " << p.getX() << "\n" << "y = " << p.getY();
    return os;
}
//input point operator
istream& operator >> (istream& is, Point& p) {
    int x, y;
    char ch1, ch2, ch3;
    is >> ch1 >> x >> ch2 >> y >> ch3;
    if(!is) return is;
    if(ch1 != '(' || ch2 != ',' || ch3 != ')') {
        is.clear(ios_base::failbit);
        throw runtime_error("bad");
        return is;
    }
    p = Point(x,y);
    return is;
}
```

Comment: Could you share what you've learned from running this in a debugger?

Comment: You code seems to work fine for me, are you sure you tested the same code you posted above?

Comment: Confirmed. There's nothing wrong with the shown code. Works for me. Compiled and checked it with valgrind. If you have a bug, it's a bug in the parts of your code that you have not shown.

Comment: Thank you guys. I found that the bug was in in the Point class. My IDE usualy generate basic source code in the files when i create new classes. Such problematic code was another constructor declaration and definition: 
"Point::Point(const Point& orig)" 
which by coincidence i found it would't be usefull to include in the question...
Commenting both out solved the issue.
It would be nice to know why this happened since i don't have a clue...
Thank you!

Comment: push_back makes a copy, if you provide the copy constructor it will use that, otherwise it will use the default compiler generated copy constructor. Therefore your copy constructor which you commented out is broken.

Comment: @Guilherme if you want to know why a certain piece of code doesn't work you're going to have post it.